# Powerquery opening files with bad extensions

Tags: html, excel, vba, powerquery, xls

One of my datasources comes as Excel "xls" files.  I put that in quotes because, under the hood, the authoring system has generated an html file and named it *myFile.xls*.

When manually opening this, Windows gives me a warning, but Excel will open it.  From Excel VBA, I can inhibit-warning, and it opens silently and correctly.  But  trying to open a folder full of such files, PowerQuery just hangs.   I've been manually opening each "xls" file and saving as .xlsx.  Any suggestions for getting rid of this manual step?

*[Running Excel 2013 under Windows 7.]*

Comment: How does it do opening just one of the files? If you have a lot of files in the folder it may take Power Query some time to read them all.

Comment: `Any suggestions for getting rid of this manual step?` Write a macro to mass convert those excel files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** in order to use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` object.

```
Dim app As Excel.Application

'If macro is running within an Excel instance, and you want to use that instance uncomment the next line
'Alternatively, use Application directly
'Set app = Application

'If you want to create a new instance, uncomment the next line
'Set app = New Excel.Application

Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim sourceFolder As String
sourceFolder = "C:\path\to\folder\of\pseudo-excel-files"

Dim destFolder As String
destFolder = fso.BuildPath(sourceFolder, "_converted")
If Not fso.FolderExists(destFolder) Then fso.CreateFolder(destFolder)

Dim fle As Scripting.File
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder(sourceFolder).Files
    Dim destPath As String
    destPath = fso.BuildPath(destFolder, fle.Name & ".xlsx")

    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = app.Workbooks.Open fle.Path
    book.SaveAs destPath, xlWorkbookDefault
    book.Close
Next
```